# How to get high quality image into word document

Tags: matlab, plot, publishing, vector-graphics, export-to-word

Manually a figure can be saved as svg file, but I cannot import it properly in word document. Is there other way around?

Comment: save as emf and keep it vector

Comment: If I remember correctly, you can copy-paste the figure from MATLAB into Word, no need to save it. (I haven't used Windows or Word in ages, so I might remember wrong.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As *Cirs Luengo* says, you could copy (`Edit -> Copy Figure`) and paste the figure form MATLAB into Word, but to ensure the picture is saved as vector-graphics you have to check your settings in `Preferences->Figure Copy Template->Copy Options`.

[image: pic1]

Comment: Someone said that it actually called `uimenufcn(gcf,'EditCopyFigure')`, but my 2015b seems doesn't have such a function.